# Are rollup fields accessible in test methods?

Tags: unit-test, roll-up-summary

When I create an object and some associated child objects in a test method, the rollup fields on the parent are always null.  Is there some common approach to handling this?

I think the same issue is described here: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/APEX-Unit-Test-and-Roll-Up-Summary-fields/td-p/153739

I'll work on a quick code example, but just wanted to get this out there in case it was an easy/common question.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a Roll-Up Summary field on Opportunity that gives the SUM of a custom Opportunity Product (OpportunityLineItem) field.

In a test case the Roll-Up Summary field was populated when I did an explicit SOQL query to pull back the new calculated value.

E.g.

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
// Set various Opp fields
insert opp;

OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
oli.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
// Set various OLI fields.
oli.FieldToRollUp__c = 1000.00;
insert oli;

// Query the Opportunity again to get the updated rollup summary field.
Opportunity oppAfterInsert = [Select RollUpSummaryField__c from Opportunity where Id= :opp.Id];
System.assertEquals(1000.00, oppAfterInsert.RollUpSummaryField__c);
```

Comment: Thanks re-querying was the step I was missing.  Good explanation.

Comment: I'm working in an org where this doesn't seem to be working.... they have some strange version of rollup helper installed so maybe thats wy

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger,

Does this still work?

Comment: @NZDev I believe so. It shouldn't be to difficult to test in a dev or scratch org.

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger, Ahhh worked out the issue, had a runonce within the trigger, fixed that & yes it does work, so thank you for the direction.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like you're not re-querying the parent for testing (please correct me if I'm wrong). The steps to get this working would be like so:

1. insert your parent record.
2. insert you child record/s.
3. query the parent record.
4. tests should contain the rollup values.